# How to Join two arrays using a delimiter in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

My graph is not getting generated properly with Chartist graph library
It wants data generated as 
     series: [   [2,4,5,5,6], [6,4,8,7]   ]
I tried to do it with this

```
 <?php echo "[". $comma_separated."],[". $comma_separated1."]"?>
```

$comma_separated = [2,4,5,5,6] 
$comma_separated1 = [6,4,8,7]

and I want $result = [ [2,4,5,5,6] , [6,4,8,7] ]

but only first array gets displayed in graph not second one ie $comma_separated1.
Static entry of these things is generating it properly.

Is there any way that I can join these two strings into a single one with a    "],["    between them and not between the contents in array.

Comment: Your question is a bit short on information and unclear what you want. Please add what you stored into: `$comma_separated` and `$comma_separated1` also add what the current + expected output is!

Comment: what does both of these arrays contain? both are just flat arrays with integers in it?

Comment: does `$comma_separated = [2,4,5,5,6]` && `$comma_separated1 = [6,4,8,7]`? if not, show us what `$comma_separated`/`$comma_separated1`  look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating the string manually, if both are already in array form, just use `json_encode`, you wouldn't need to manually add each string if the batches continue to grow:

```
// example input
$comma_separated = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // 1 - 5
$comma_separated2 = array(6, 7, 8, 9, 10); // 6 - 10

$result = json_encode(array($comma_separated, $comma_separated2));
echo $result; // [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/aB71Zk)

The example above parses them from an array form into string. If the input came from a string form (literal comma delimited string), then you need to explode it first, then cast all elements with int, so that in turn `json_encode` will treat them as int:

```
// example input
$comma_separated = '1,2,3,4,5';
$comma_separated2 = '6,7,8,9,10';
// int casting
$comma_separated = array_map('intval', explode(',', $comma_separated));
$comma_separated2 = array_map('intval', explode(',', $comma_separated2));

$result = json_encode(array($comma_separated, $comma_separated2));
echo $result; // [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
```

[Sample Output 2](http://codepad.viper-7.com/e1SEwb)

Comment: The question is the problem here, since there are too many unknowns here! And we don't see the full code from OP and what his goal is. So all we can do here is just guesswork.

Comment: @Rizier123 yeah the OP hasn't been able to answer unknown points yet, but in the event that the input is a string, i just added another just in case

Comment: That's what I mean ^. You write all variants and hope that one matches with OP's real code, but you can't known it you can only guess. The question is just bad and unclear, since many things are missing and OP isn't updating it.

Comment: @Ghost 
you have properly understood my output  
but how will "  ],[" get inserted in between

Comment: @Nikhil no, you don't need to take care of that, `json_encode` does that for you already, actually it doesn't matter how many you got there, it'll add it there automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Hope the mentioned helps you.

```
<?php

$array1 = array('2','4','5','5','6');
$array2 = array('6','4','8','7');

$finalString = array($array1, $array2);

print "<pre>";
print_r($finalString);
print "</pre>";   

?>
```